# Not able to gem install [anything]

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, jruby

I am on macOS 11.6.8 and have installed jruby-9.2.11.0 .
When i am trying to `gem install bundler -v 2.1.4`  or any other gem. I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (NameError)
    cannot load (ext) (org.jruby.ext.openssl.OpenSSL)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

openssl version - OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022)